# How do I make my command accessible?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm just taking over an asp.net/vb site, and I'm definitely still learning.  I'm receiving the following error: BC30451: 'ByOwner' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

I call a datasource with:

```
<asp:GridView ID="CaseCountByOwner" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" DataSourceID="ByOwner"
```

And here's what is in the codefile:

```
     Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    HitMe.AddHit(Request.UserHostAddress, Request.UserAgent, Request.Url.ToString)

    Dim user As String = Request.QueryString("user")
    If user.Length() = 0 Then
        Return
    Else

        ByOwner.SelectCommand = "select " & _
 "TU.login_name as Owner," & _
 "( select " & _
     "   count(1)" & _
  "from table_case TC1 with (NOLOCK) " & _
  "join table_user TU1 with (NOLOCK) on TU1.objid = TC1.case_owner2user " & _
  "join table_gbst_elm TGE1 with (NOLOCK) on TGE1.objid = TC1.casests2gbst_elm  " & _
        "where TC1.case_wip2wipbin Is Not null " & _
        "and TC1.x_casetype not in ('Esc- Support','CRel - Wellness') " & _
  "and TU1.login_name = TU.login_name " & _
  "and TGE1.title not in ('File CR') " & _
 ") as AllCases," & _
 "( select " & _
        "count(1)" & _
  "from table_case TC2 with (NOLOCK) " & _
  "join table_user TU2 with (NOLOCK) on TU2.objid = TC2.case_owner2user " & _
  "join table_gbst_elm TGE2 with (NOLOCK) on TGE2.objid = TC2.casests2gbst_elm  " & _
        "where TC2.case_wip2wipbin Is Not null " & _
        "and TC2.x_casetype not in ('Esc- Support','CRel - Wellness') " & _
  "and TGE2.title not in ('File CR','Suggested Resolution','Suggestion Filed','Await SW Rel/Dev','Pending ClientAction') " & _
  "and TU2.login_name = TU.login_name" & _
 ") as Workable," & _
 "( select " & _
        "count(1)" & _
  "from table_case TC3 with (NOLOCK) " & _
  "join table_user TU3 with (NOLOCK) on TU3.objid = TC3.case_owner2user " & _
  "join table_gbst_elm TGE3 with (NOLOCK) on TGE3.objid = TC3.casests2gbst_elm  " & _
  "join table_gbst_elm SEVERITY3 with (NOLOCK) on TC3.respsvrty2gbst_elm = SEVERITY3.objid " & _
        "where TC3.case_wip2wipbin Is Not null " & _
        "and TC3.x_casetype not in ('Esc- Support','CRel - Wellness') " & _
  "and SEVERITY3.title in ('Down','Critical - ANF') " & _
  "and TGE3.title not in ('File CR','Suggestion Filed','Await SW Rel/Dev','Pending ClientAction') " & _
  "and TU3.login_name = TU.login_name" & _
 ") as DownCritical, " & _
  "(    select " & _
        "count(1)" & _
  "from table_case TC4 with (NOLOCK) " & _
  "join table_user TU4 with (NOLOCK) on TU4.objid = TC4.case_owner2user " & _
  "join table_gbst_elm TGE4 with (NOLOCK) on TGE4.objid = TC4.casests2gbst_elm  " & _
        "where TC4.case_wip2wipbin Is Not null " & _
        "and TC4.x_casetype not in ('Esc- Support','CRel - Wellness') " & _
  "and TGE4.title in ('Testing Data') " & _
  "and TU4.login_name = TU.login_name" & _
 ") as TestingData " & _
"from table_user TU with (NOLOCK)" & _
"where TU.login_name in (select TU.login_name from table_employee TE with (NOLOCK) " & _
"join table_user TU with (NOLOCK) on TE.employee2user = TU.objid and TU.status = 1 " & _
"where TE.emp_supvr2employee = (select EMPTE.emp_supvr2employee " & _
"from table_user EMPTU with (NOLOCK) " & _
"join table_employee EMPTE with (NOLOCK) on EMPTE.employee2user = EMPTU.objid " & _
"where EMPTU.login_name like ('" & user & "') " & _
")) " & _
"order by 1 "
    End If


End Sub
Dim casesTotal As Integer = 0
Dim workableTotal As Integer = 0
Dim downTotal As Integer = 0
Dim testingTotal As Integer = 0
Protected Sub CaseCountByOwner_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        casesTotal += (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "AllCases"))
        workableTotal += (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Workable"))
        downTotal += (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DownCritical"))
        testingTotal += (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "TestingData"))
    ElseIf e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
        e.Row.Cells(0).Text = "Totals:"
        e.Row.Cells(1).Text = casesTotal
        e.Row.Cells(2).Text = workableTotal
        e.Row.Cells(3).Text = downTotal
        e.Row.Cells(4).Text = testingTotal

        e.Row.Font.Bold = True
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub UpdateTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    LiveQueue.DataBind()
    LabelLiveQueue.Text = "Updated: " + DateAndTime.Now.ToString()
End Sub
Protected Sub UpdateTimer2_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    LiveAgents.DataBind()
    LabelLiveAgents.Text = "Updated: " + DateAndTime.Now.ToString()
End Sub
Dim callsTotal As Integer = 0
Dim offeredTotal As Integer = 0
Dim handledTotal As Integer = 0
Protected Sub LiveQueueGridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        callsTotal += (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Holding"))
        offeredTotal += (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Offered"))
        handledTotal += (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Handled"))
    ElseIf e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
        e.Row.Cells(0).Text = "Totals:"
        e.Row.Cells(1).Text = callsTotal
        e.Row.Cells(3).Text = offeredTotal
        e.Row.Cells(4).Text = handledTotal

        e.Row.Font.Bold = True
    End If
End Sub

Dim TotalCalls As Int32 = 0
Function GetCalls(ByVal Calls As Int32) As Int32
    TotalCalls += Calls
    Return Calls
End Function
Function GetTotal() As Int32
    Return TotalCalls
End Function


Protected Sub BtnExportGrid_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As EventArgs)
    '  pass the grid that for exporting ...
    Me.CaseView.GridLines = GridLines.Both
    GridViewExportUtil.Export("Cases.xls", Me.CaseView)
End Sub
```

End Class

Any help is greatly appreciated, and even more appreciated would be a link to a good resource on getting started with .net applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a a `SqlDataSource` somewhere in your page with ID "ByOwner"

For example:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ByOwner" runat="server" />
```

Notice that you are declaring your datasource of the GridView to be "ByOwner".

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you to use SP,  instead of writing hardcoded query in sql, you can write stored procedure, which will give optimum results.

[Stored Procedure](http://www.dbtutorials.com/advanced/using-stored-procedures-cs.aspx)

[Stored Procedure with C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/gtomar/storedprocedure12052007003126AM/storedprocedure.aspx)

[Stored procedure to return scalar values](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134930/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/062905-1.aspx)

Comment: Optimum is totally a new form of measuring optimoniums.

Comment: This is my next step.  Lots of queries to convert to SP's.  Thatnks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find where the object `ByOwner` is declared.  Is there some control on the same page with an ID attribute of ByOwner?